# Error while installing feature camel-consul in karaf

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-karaf

**Problem**

I'm trying to install the camel feature **camel-consul 2.22.2** in a **karaf 4.2.2** environment.

When I launch

```
feature:install camel-consul
```

from karaf terminal I get this error:

> org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=camel-consul; type=karaf.feature; version="[2.22.2,2.22.2]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=camel-consul)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.22.2)(version<=2.22.2))" [caused by: Unable to resolve camel-consul/2.22.2: missing requirement [camel-consul/2.22.2] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.camel.camel-consul; type=osgi.bundle; version="[2.22.2,2.22.2]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.camel.camel-consul/2.22.2: missing requirement [org.apache.camel.camel-consul/2.22.2] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=com.orbitz.consul.async)" [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1: missing requirement [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=22.0.0)(!(version>=23.0.0)))"]]]
>           at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343)
>           at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:392)
>           at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:378)
>           at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:332)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:257)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:388)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1025)
>           at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:964)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve camel-consul/2.22.2: missing requirement [camel-consul/2.22.2] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.camel.camel-consul; type=osgi.bundle; version="[2.22.2,2.22.2]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.camel.camel-consul/2.22.2: missing requirement [org.apache.camel.camel-consul/2.22.2] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=com.orbitz.consul.async)" [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1: missing requirement [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=22.0.0)(!(version>=23.0.0)))"]]
>           at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343)
>           ... 12 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve org.apache.camel.camel-consul/2.22.2: missing requirement [org.apache.camel.camel-consul/2.22.2] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=com.orbitz.consul.async)" [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1: missing requirement [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=22.0.0)(!(version>=23.0.0)))"]
>           at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343)
>           ... 13 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1: missing requirement [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=22.0.0)(!(version>=23.0.0)))"
>           at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343)
>           ... 14 more
>
> Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement
>   [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=camel-consul; type=karaf.feature;
>   version="[2.22.2,2.22.2]";
>   filter:="(&(osgi.identity=camel-consul)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.22.2)(version<=2.22.2))" [caused by: Unable to resolve camel-consul/2.22.2: missing requirement
>   [camel-consul/2.22.2] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=org.apache.camel.camel-consul; type=osgi.bundle;
>   version="[2.22.2,2.22.2]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to
>   resolve org.apache.camel.camel-consul/2.22.2: missing requirement
>   [org.apache.camel.camel-consul/2.22.2] osgi.wiring.package;
>   filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=com.orbitz.consul.async)" [caused by:
>   Unable to resolve
>   org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1: missing
>   requirement
>   [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.orbitz-consul-client/1.2.0.1]
>   osgi.wiring.package;
>   filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=22.0.0)(!(version>=23.0.0)))"]]]

---

**Question**

Why I get this error? There are some tricks to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try with a newer version of Camel

Comment: It works with camel 3.0.0-M2 on karaf 4.2.5